# How can I split an eight character string into four variables?

Tags: c#

I hava a string like this:

```
var id = "01020304";
```

Is there a simple way I can split this into four variables called pr, pa, fo, it  Each variable needs to have the two characters of the string. Looking for an elegant solution if it exists.

Comment: If you tell us what the names pr, pa, fo and it mean, we can give you an answer with more semantic meaning!

Comment: Tried using Substrings but I know there are some clever guys here who always come up with some great solutions. Everyone always gets an upvote for helping.

Comment: How could it be any better than 4 separate calls to substring when there are 4 different variables (as opposed to an array or similar)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you have four distinct variables, you can't get much more elegant than using Substring:

```
var pr = id.Substring(0, 2);
var pa = id.Substring(2, 2);
var fo = id.Substring(4, 2);
var it = id.Substring(6);
```

Were you looking for an array of four 2-character substrings, you could get fancier:

```
var parts = new string[4];
for (int i = 0 ; i != parts.Length ; i ++) {
    parts[i] = id.Substring(2*i, 2);
}
```

**EDIT:** The same can be done with a LINQ expression:

```
var parts = Enumerable
    .Range(0, id.Length/2)
    .Select(i => x.Substring(2*i, 2))
    .ToArray();
```

Comment: I am sure that your looping construct can also be done using a clever LINQ query...

Comment: @Oded You are probably right. But if you cannot write this construct LINQ without thinking, I bet it is going to be too fancy to remain readable :)

Comment: @Oded, Re LINQ, something like grouping on `Math.Floor(index / 2.0f)` i'd imagine, but yeah, not really straightforward to write or read.

Comment: @GeorgeDuckett - Possibly. Still - ugly and not very readable.

Comment: It certainly can be done using LINQ (see my answer below), but as you guys said, the code is not that easy to read if you can only use the extension methods provided by the Framework.

Comment: @user1016253 Why would it throw an exception when i is zero? Try this out locally, and let me know what exception you see.

Comment: @Oded I found a reasonably straightforward LINQ expression that hides the loop, and remains readable. Once you start with `Enumerable.Range(0, 4)`, the rest is simple.

Answer (score 6):

You can use [`Substring`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.substring.aspx):

```
pr = id.Substring(0, 2);
pa = id.Substring(2, 2);
fo = id.Substring(4, 2);
it = id.Substring(6, 2);
```

Answer (score 5):

Try regular expression.

```
 var id = "01020304";
 string pat = "(?:(\\d{2}))";

 var result = Regex.Split(id, pat).Where(p=>p!=string.Empty);
 foreach (var t in result)
 {
   Console.WriteLine(t);
 }
```

Answer (score 4):

If you are always going to have an input of 8 characters and always require 4 variables, you can simply split the string with the `Substring(...)` method:

```
var id = "01020304";
string pr = id.Substring(0, 2);
string pa = id.Substring(2, 2);
string fo = id.Substring(4, 2);
string it = id.Substring(6, 2);
```

Otherwise, you can employ a method of running through a `for` loop and splitting off two characters at a time.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a solution with a loop, which would support strings of this format, any length:

```
string id  = "01020304";
int length = id.Length;

int[] holder = new int[length/2];

for (int i = 0; i < length/2; i++) {
    holder[i] = id.Substring(i*2, 2);
}
```

Comment: With an odd length string, the final character will be ignored.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a version using Linq.

Interestingly enough, this is not so easy to achieve with just the built-in operators. The version below just uses the Linq extension methods that come with the .NET framework:

```
var result = "01020304".ToCharArray().
           Select((c,i) => new { idx = i % 2 == 1 ? i - 1 : i, ch = c }).
           GroupBy(e => e.idx, 
              (k,g) => new String(g.Select(e => e.ch).ToArray()));
```

If you use the [morelinq Extensions](http://code.google.com/p/morelinq/) the query can be simplified to

```
 var result = "01020304".ToCharArray().
                     Batch(2).Select(ca => new String(ca.ToArray()));
```